# Java GPA array scanner input and calculation

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, user-input

I'm trying to use a scanner input to calculate a GPA with an array.  I would think a while loop would be best but I'm not sure.  I have a method that would attempt to calculate the GPA from the scanner input into the array.  My code is attached.  Let me know what's the simplest way to do so.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class gpaArrayInput
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int i = 0;
    //double average;
    int grades[]=new int [i];


    for (i=0; i<grades.length;i++){

    System.out.println ("Enter your final class grades for the semester: ");
        grades[i]=scan.nextInt();

    averageMethod();
    }}




public static void averageMethod()
{
    double sum=0;
    double average;

    for(int i=0; i<grades.length;i++)
    {

        sum += grades[i];

    }

    average = sum/grades.length;


    System.out.println("Your grade average is: "+average);
}

}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, add the homework tag.

Comment: This is not homework, it's just personal practice.

Comment: Why call averageMethod() in your loop? Get all the grades first then call `averageMethod()` once instead of repeatedly calling it. Also why declare an array of size 0? Ask the user to enter the number of grades for scanner. Finally I would use    System.out.Print("Enter your final..\n"); for better output.

Comment: It's very hard to believe this isn't homework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [Scanner documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

After a quick test, this seems to work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ClassNamesShouldBeCapitalized
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner gradeScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int gradeCounter = 0;
        int gradeTotal = 0;

        System.out.println("Input grade: " );

        while(gradeScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int nextGrade = gradeScanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Recorded grade: " + nextGrade);
            System.out.println("Input grade: " );
            gradeTotal += nextGrade;
            gradeCounter++;
        }

        if (gradeCounter > 0) {
            double avg = gradeTotal / gradeCounter;
            System.out.println("Here's your average: " + avg);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No grades found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in your example. If the first input is not a int, an exception will be thrown. Why don't you use while instead of do while?

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if that Exception had anything to do with the do while loop, but I fixed it. I was getting a divide by zero exception (obviously) if the first input was bunk.